# Passing Angular component in another component constructor

Tags: angular, angular7

I am new to Angular v2+ and I have seen a code that gets a component object in constructor like this:

```
  constructor(private host: MapComponent) {
  }
```

[Full code is here](https://github.com/quentin-ol/ngx-openlayers/blob/master/src/components/view.component.ts). Is this a true way?

Comment: What does "Is this a true way?" mean? Are you asking if that code is correct? If so, why don't you just test it?

Comment: @JBNizet your answer shows that you does not understand questions right. Code is already working. But all working code is not true. if so, design patterns would not be developed. (If you are owner of stackoverflow, you can play by oneself here.)

Comment: no. First, my answer is not an answer, but a comment. And it simply asks you what you your question means, which is unclear to me, and to at least 2 other people who voted to close it as unclear. So, maybe I can understand questions, but you can't ask them clearly? How about just clarifying your question, instead of patronizing me? I answered to 13,702 questions here. So I guess that, in general, I'm able to understand questions.

Comment: Ok, If you answered them all like that, you could answer 500,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to this [architecture-components](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components) you cant pass that way

There are several ways how Angular components can pass data around:

Using `@Input` and `@Output`

By injecting parent component through constructor or child components through `@ViewChild`, `@ViewChildren`, `@ContentChild`, `@ContentChildren` and directly calling component’s API

Using services (this covers state management libraries like ngrx)

Using router parameters

First two methods can only be used when we have parent — child relationship

between our components — one of the components is the parent node in the

Answer (score -1):

You can inject component but by using @ViewChild decorator.